# Setting up a CS: Source server to be accessible from the internet

Tags: steam, hosting, counter-strike-source

I am trying to set up a Counter-Strike: Source server so that I can play online with my friends. The server is simply a Windows 10 Desktop PC.

I followed the instructions using `steam.cmd`, as per [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD) and [here](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?l=german&id=397365275).

Now, when I execute `C:\steamcmd\css\srcds.exe -console -game cstrike -insecure +maxplayers 16 +map de_dust2`, a window opens and the following is displayed:

```
66.7 fps  0/16 on map         de_dust2
Console initialized.
Using Breakpad minidump system. Version: 5394425 AppID: 232330
Loaded 1335 VPK file hashes from C:\steamcmd\css\cstrike\cstrike_pak.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 1335 VPK file hashes from C:\steamcmd\css\cstrike\cstrike_pak.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 1218 VPK file hashes from C:\steamcmd\css\hl2\hl2_textures.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 574 VPK file hashes from C:\steamcmd\css\hl2\hl2_sound_vo_english.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 383 VPK file hashes from C:\steamcmd\css\hl2\hl2_sound_misc.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 446 VPK file hashes from C:\steamcmd\css\hl2\hl2_misc.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 5 VPK file hashes from C:\steamcmd\css\platform\platform_misc.vpk for pure server operation.
server.dll loaded for "Counter-Strike: Source"
maxplayers set to 16
Unknown command "r_decal_cullsize"
maxplayers set to 16
Network: IP 192.168.178.28, mode MP, dedicated Yes, ports 27015 SV / 27005 CL
Initializing Steam libraries for INSECURE Internet server.  Authentication and VAC not requested.
No account token specified; logging into anonymous game server account.  (Use sv_setsteamaccount to login to a persistent account.)
Executing dedicated server config file server.cfg
Using map cycle file 'cfg/mapcycle_default.txt'.  ('cfg\mapcycle.txt' was not found.)
Set motd from file 'cfg/motd_default.txt'.  ('cfg/motd.txt' was not found.)
Set motd_text from file 'cfg/motd_text_default.txt'.  ('cfg/motd_text.txt' was not found.)
SV_ActivateServer: setting tickrate to 66.7
"bot_allow_machine_guns" = "1"
 game replicated
 - If nonzero, bots may use the machine gun.
'sourcemod/sourcemod.cfg' not present; not executing.
Server is hibernating
Connection to Steam servers successful.
   Public IP is 87.XX.XXX.XX.
Assigned anonymous gameserver Steam ID [A:1:3375420425:14562].
VAC secure mode disabled.
```

In particular, `sourcemod/sourcemod.cfg not present; not executing.` intrigues me (line 6 from the bottom).

Does this mean the server is not running?

When I open the game and search for the server using the indicated public IP and the ports `27015`, `27005` etc., it says: "Server is not responding".
On my router, I opened ports 26900 - 27020, which should cover the necessary range as per [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Dedicated_Server).

When connecting using the PC's local IP, the server is found in the server list.

Comment: Some routers don't allow loopbacks like that (you can't connect to your own public IP), you should be using your internal IP to connect (192.168.178.28:27015). You may also want to make sure your Windows firewall has those ports open too.

Comment: Thank you.
I had a Raspberry Pi running, connected to the same router, where I had a webserver that I could access from the Desktop using the Pi's public IP. Would this counterprove your first idea for my setup, or am I missing something?

Comment: If there are rules that have been created for that kind of routing then it can certainly work. Or if it is a smart enough router it will do it for you. And because you have a public server already, there may be rules where it directs all traffic to the Pi device which would also explain why it isn't connecting. What is the model of the device?

Comment: The router is a Fritz!Box 7490 with newest firmware. However, as I just realized, websites like https://canyouseeme.org/ and https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ do not show the ports as open, although I opened them in the firewall. And the Pi is also no longer running.

Comment: Is there more than one computer in the house? Can you connect to the server using the internal IP and port? I'd start my testing there first. Also canyouseeme only returns a response if something responds. You can have the port open on the firewall, but it will still show as down if there is nothing on the other end responding to the open port.

Comment: There are several computers, laptops, mobile phones more or less constantly in the network, but none else is running a webserver, or something. 
I can connect in-game to the server when using the internal IP and port.

Comment: Do you have  something like `exec sourcemod/sourcemod.cfg` in your server.cfg without having sourcemod installed? That would explain this line. Also to test the loopback problem you could hook up another pc in your house to a mobile phone and then try joining the server.

Comment: Of this type, I only have `exec banned_user.cfg` and `exec banned_ip.cfg` in the `server.cfg`. I hooked up another pc in the house to a mobile hotspot and could not find the server.

Comment: "I can connect in-game to the server when using the internal IP and port." From the same computer as the host or from a different computer?

Comment: The same computer.

Comment: Same computer connections will work 99% of the time since the source and the destination are the same. The computer knows how to route traffic to itself and there won't be rules stopping that. If you can connect from another computer then there isn't a firewall issue. If you can't, I would start there.